# How android client receive message if the client goes back to online after the server sent message through firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, delphi, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have sample projects for server and android client written in Delphi 10.2.3. The server sends a message to the android client through Firebase Cloud Messaging. The client receives and displays the message.

It has no problem to receive the message on the android client side if the client app is online or runs in the background before the server sends the message. I am facing a problem that the client app is unable to receive the message if the client app goes back to online after the server sent the message. How to solve this problem?

Below are sample projects.

Server:

```
procedure TForm2.SendClick(Sender: TObject);
var R: IHTTPResponse;
    M: TBytesStream;
    o: THTTPClient;
    J: TJSONObject;
    A: TBytes;
    S: string;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  S := {"to":"token","time_to_live":120,"data":{"title":"test title","body":"test body"}}

  M := TBytesStream.Create;
  o := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    J := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S) as TJSONObject;
    if Assigned(J) then begin
      try
        A := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(J.ToString);
        M.Write(A, Length(A));
        M.Position := 0;
      finally
        J.DisposeOf;
      end;
    end;

    o.AcceptCharSet := 'UTF-8';
    o.ContentType := 'application/json';
    o.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'key=FirebaseProjectServerKey';
    R := o.Post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', M);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Status Code=%s' + sLineBreak + 'Status Text=%s' + sLineBreak + 'Content=%s', [R.StatusCode.ToString, R.StatusText, R.ContentAsString]));
  finally
    M.DisposeOf;
    o.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

Client:

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.StdCtrls,
  System.PushNotification, FMX.PushNotification.Android;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
   Memo1: TMemo;
   CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
   Button1: TButton;
   procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   procedure CheckBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
 private
   FPushService: TPushService;
   FPushServiceConnection: TPushServiceConnection;
   procedure OnChange(Sender: TObject; AChange: TPushService.TChanges);
   procedure OnReceivedNotification(Sender: TObject; const ANotification:
        TPushServiceNotification);
 public
   procedure AfterConstruction; override;
   procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
 end;

 var
   Form1: TForm1;

 implementation

 uses System.Threading, FMX.Platform;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FPushService :=TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
  FPushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := 'FirebaseProjectSenderID';

  FPushServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(FPushService);
  FPushServiceConnection.OnChange := OnChange;
  FPushServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceivedNotification;
end;

procedure TForm1.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FPushServiceConnection.DisposeOf;
  FPushService.DisposeOf;
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;

  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      FPushServiceConnection.Active := CheckBox1.IsChecked;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.OnChange(Sender: TObject; AChange: TPushService.TChanges);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Token=' + FPushService.DeviceTokenValue[TPushService.TDeviceTokenNames.DeviceToken]);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnReceivedNotification(Sender: TObject; const ANotification: TPushServiceNotification);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Notification=' + ANotification.DataObject.ToString);
end;
```

Comment: The behavior you mentioned is the usual behavior for FCM. A message stays enqueued on the FCM servers and is sent as soon as applicable (when the device goes online) -- see [Lifetime of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

Comment: Are you sure about the JSON data format? On https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl the TTL is specified using "android":{
      "ttl":"4500s"
    }

Comment: can you try ALFirebaseMessagingDemo.apk demo from alcinoe  https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe . you will maybe need to compile it yourself to put your server key, you can found the source code in the demo directory.